# Calling Javascript method in hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, hyperlink, string-literals

In my MVC Razor page, I can call Javascript method successfully in the hyperlink below:

```
<a id="lnkAddAccount" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" 
    onclick='openModal("#div1", "#div2")'>Details
</a>
```

However, when having to use this hyperlink in string, I encounter "SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script" error.

```
'<a title="Details" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline grey-salsa" 
    onclick=openModal("#div1", "#div2")><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>'
```

How to call this Javascript method from the latter hyperlink?

Comment: Could you please post as an answer? Thanks...

Comment: Its the 21st century - stop polluting your markup with behavior and use [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hmmm, actually I have seen this approach several times before and I think it is really good idea to switch to it. However, I am not sure if there is a disadvantage of using it. Is there any? On the other hand, in order to using this approach, could you please inform me about the page from which I can get information about the all the events corresponding to standart events i.e. onClick, onLoad, etc? Thanks a lot...

Comment: [jquery events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/)

Comment: Ok, I will keep in mind that and change all of the javascript method calls :) I hope there is no disadvantage to use them in this way?

Comment: @StephenMuecke In my MVC project, I have a Javascript method in an _Layout page and I call this from 2 different Views by 2 different button click. So, in this situation if I use **jQuery Events** I think I will have to repeat the method body for both of the button click event. Is there a better way or is it good idea to use the approach in my question? Could you please clarify me about this problem?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I meant to use **button.addEventListener("click", function() { ... });** What do you suggest in the situation explained my previous comment?

Comment: You only need one script in the layout. You could give your buttons a class name and them the script would be `$('.yourClassName').click(function() { // do something });`

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for all of these valuable information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue: you removed the quotes surrounding the value of the `onclick`. The quotes are optional in HTML (but strongly recommended). However, when the value has spaces like in your case, the quotes are mandatory.

The second issue: you have quotes surrounding the parameters of the `openModal`. That's good, but if you add the quotes to solve the first issue above, you end up with quotes inside quotes, in which case, you'll have to escape the inner quotes with `\`.

So you have two solutions:

**Solution 1** (not recommended): remove the space in the value of the `onclick` so you don't need to surround it with quotes:

```
'<a title="Details" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline grey-salsa" onclick=openModal("#div1","#div2")><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>'
```

This solution will work, but not recommended because it is strongly recommended to always use quotes surrounding the values.

**Solution 2**: surround the value with quotes and escape the inner quotes with `\`:

```
'<a title="Details" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline grey-salsa" onclick="openModal(\'#div1\', \'#div2\')"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>'
```

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed explanations. The first solution is working, but the second not (still the same error). As you recommended, I want to use 2nd Solution. Any idea to fix it?

Comment: Yes, sorry, the inner quotes must be single quotes. I copied them from your code and forgot to change them. You cannot have the same type of quotes inside each other. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes.

```
'<a title="Details" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline grey-salsa" 
    onclick="openModal(\"#div1\", \"#div2\")"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>'
```

Notice that had to escape the inner quotes.

On the whole, making HTML from strings is just messy. Depending on your tech  stack there are usually better ways.

Comment: I applied the escape characters exactly as in your example, but still the same error :( Any idea?

Comment: You'll have to update your question with enough code we can see the assign statement.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
'<a title="Details" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline grey-salsa" onclick="openModal(\"#div1\", \"#div2\")"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>'
```

don't give line break in between or else concatenation with line break